# How do I get the canonical slot value out of an Alexa request

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am attempting to write an Alexa skill with custom slots, but Alexa ignores my synonyms. Apparently `Alexa.getSlotValue(requestEnvelope, 'intentSlotName');` will retrieve the actual spoken words, as opposed to the canonical value. I am comparing against the canonical values to determine program behavior, so I would really prefer my slots to return the canonical value when I hit a synonym, rather than the synonym itself.

How do I do this? I have been having some trouble finding the answer in the Alexa documentation, and the answers I do see seem really complicated for behavior that seems like it should practically be default (and they didn't work when I tried them)

Is there anything like

```js
Alexa.getCanonicalSlotValue(requestEnvelope, 'intentSlotName');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no helpers in the ASK SDK to access canonical value, but you can create a simple function to fetch it. You'll want to start with using the `getSlot` helper, which returns a Slot object with resolved entities as defined [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-apis-for-nodejs/blob/master/ask-sdk-model/index.ts#L563).

```
const getCanonicalSlot = (slot) => {
    if (slot.resolutions && slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority.length) {
        for (let resolution of slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority) {
            if (resolution.status && resolution.status.code === 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
                return resolution.values[0].value.name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call this in your handler:

```
let mySlot = Alexa.getSlot(requestEnvelope, 'mySlot');
let mySlotCanonical = getCanonicalSlot(mySlot);
```

I recommend experimenting in the Test tab on the Alexa Developer Console (or simply logging requests in full) to better understand why the code above works. For example, the JSON for a basic slot implementation will be returned as such:

```
"slots": {
    "mySlot": {
        "name": "mySlot",
        "value": "bar",
        "resolutions": {
            "resolutionsPerAuthority": [{
                "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.****.mySlotType",
                "status": {
                    "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                },
                "values": [{
                    "value": {
                        "name": "foo",
                        "id": "acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8"
                    }
                }]
            }]
        },
        "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
        "source": "USER"
    }
}
```