# Alexa having trouble understanding my voice input

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am working on an Alexa Skill and am having trouble for Alexa to understand my voice input. Therefore the utterances are not properly matched with the required slots... and alexa is always re asking or getting stuck.
Here are some examples:
affirm: f.m., a from

Speedbird: Speedboard, speaker, speed but, speed bird, spirit, speedbath

wind: windies (wind is), when is home (wind is calm)

runway 03: runway sarah three

takeoff: the cough

Any solution to training Alexa to properly understand me? Or should I just write as utterance all these "false" utterances so alexa will match my intents properly?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance to train the language understanding itself of Alexa.

Yes, as you wrote: I would just take these false utterances as matches for your intent.
This seems also what is recommended by [amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/asr/about-asr.html?&sc_category=Owned&sc_channel=EM&sc_campaign=HVD&sc_publisher=NP&sc_content=Content&sc_country=WW&sc_segment=ASK&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWXpreE16UXdNalZtWW1SbSIsInQiOiJsOGZkSXY4UnM2SGtwbDAxXC9qV2g3bmJwQVVobWZrWUdJSjJzXC9rZkdXZk16bVpHUHRpOG9WY043XC82Sm5Jc0JLMXRVM3pjVFVZRm8zMXMrbjQ0d3lvbWpcL2hcL2cra2puVFM3OFE2dGxnR0g0OVFHdkp4bnlMcWZRdlNic2Q0WWw5In0%3D):

> ...might show you that sometimes Alexa misunderstands the word "mocha" as
> "milk." To mitigate this issue, you can map an utterance directly to
> an Alexa intent to help improve Alexa's understanding within your
> skill.  ....

> two common ways to improve ASR accuracy are to map an intent value or
> a slot value to a failing utterance

Maybe give an other person a try to see if it's recognized the same way as your speech.

Comment: Ok, I did try it out with a native speaker (which I am not and thought it would be my dialect, German ;) but Alexa still is not understanding everything as I would like. So I guess I have to match these false utterances to my intents. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Word-Only Slots**

If you're still struggling with this, you should try adding more variations to your slot values (synonyms are an option if you have specific interpretations that keep repeating). Consider adding synonyms like `speed bird` for `Speedbird` (and `take off` for `takeoff`). Non-standard word slots will not resolve as accurately as common words. By breaking `Speedbird` into two words, Alexa should more successfully recognize the slot. Information about synonyms are here:

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/define-synonyms-and-ids-for-slot-type-values-entity-resolution.html#sample-slot-type-definition-and-intentrequest

Once you've done this, you'll want to grab the canonical value of the slot, not the interpreted value (e.g. you want `Speedbird` not `speedboard`).

To see an example, scroll to the very last JSON code block. The scenario described in this request is that the user said the word `track` with is a synonym for the slot value `song` in their request. You'll see the MediaType value is `track` (what the user said) but if you take a look at the resolutions object, inside the values array, the first value object is the actual slot value `song` (what you want) associated with the synonym.

This StackOverflow goes a little more into the details on how you get that value:
[How do I get the canonical slot value out of an Alexa request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569514/how-do-i-get-the-canonical-slot-value-out-of-an-alexa-request)

**Word and Number Slots**

In the case of the "runway 03" example, consider breaking this into two different slots, e.g. `{RunwaySlot : Custom} {Number : Amazon.Number}`. You'll have better luck with these more complex slots. The same is true for an example like "red airplane," you'll want to break it into two slots: `{Color : Amazon.Color} {VehicleSlot : Custom}`

.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#number